# How to record a video when it is playing in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

My need is that when Playing a video in movie player when I tap record button the video plays and at a time the video shud also record.Can any one suggest how to do this.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

thanks to all,
Monish.

Comment: Please clarify. You to want change the behaviour of someone elses app? Or you wish to record through one of the cams while playing a video?

Comment: Actually I am playing a video in my application and when playing my application when a tap a button record the recording of the playing video shud start in background.

Comment: @WarrenBurton Can we capture video while playing another video in movieplayer ? Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unlikely that this would ever be possible. If it were, it would open a huge copyright hole. For instance, you could buy a movie on iTunes, then have your app 'record' it while it's playing in Movie Player and then send the movie elsewhere. This will almost certainly not be possible using the released SDK API, and the task would likely be quite non-trivial even in a jailbroken content. Even if you figured something out, I can't see any way that an app with this functionality would be seen as being in compliance with the App Store guidelines. (Sections 8.5, 9.1, and 22.4 all look relevant here.)

Comment: Can we capture video while playing another video in movieplayer ? Please help me..